# How to check ID_CAP_MAP is open?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

For example code as below :

```
if ( ID_CAP_MAP is openning)
{
     string location=getLocation (latitude, logitude)
}
 else
      return ;
```

Problem : I don't know how to check if ID_CAP_MAP is openning?please help me.

Comment: http://www.nickharris.net/2011/01/check-if-a-capability-is-enabled-in-wmappmanifest-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Also, why are you trying to do this? If you use the Map control and don't have the correct manifest permission, your app will a) crash and b) not pass certificaiton